# Using docker in Jenkins pipeline fails

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkinsfile I am trying to download docker image and use in this docker image for all the git pull and frontend build stuff.

My jenkinsfile is so far:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {   
       stage('Install Docker-CE') {
            steps {
                sh '''curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
                sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
                sudo apt-get update
                sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce'''
            }
        }
        stage('Start Docker') {
            steps {
                sh 'sudo service docker start'
                sh 'sudo service docker status'
            }
        }
        stage('Verify Docker') {
            steps {
                sh 'sudo docker run hello-world'
            }
        }

        stage('Build Back End') {
              steps {
                  git ([url : 'https://github....git', branch : 'develop', credentialsId : 'xxx' ]) 
              }
        }
}
```

The docker is installed and running, because in the 'Start Docker' step when I run sudo service docker status, it says: **Docker is running**

but when trying to do 'hello world' in the next step, it says **`docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.`**

I also tried to run docker daemon with: `sudo dockerd` but it didn't help, this is the part of the output:

```
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.782471391Z" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: permission denied" storage-driver=overlay2
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.782647045Z" level=error msg="exec: \"fuse-overlayfs\": executable file not found in $PATH" storage-driver=fuse-overlayfs
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.783389746Z" level=warning msg="[graphdriver] WARNING: the aufs storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release"
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.810999832Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.811283522Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.816297382Z" level=warning msg="Running iptables --wait -t nat -L -n failed with message: `iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)\nPerhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`, error: exit status 3"
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.887136525Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.887859247Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
time="2021-07-28T08:45:04.887889167Z" level=info msg="stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown" module=libcontainerd
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

Comment: Maybe because between your  install and start command docker is not yet ready. You may need to create some kind of wait on service. Or use docker itself to compose jenkins and communicate between services over a network bridge.

Comment: Not sure, because after I start the docker via sudo service docker start, I immediately check it's status via sudo service docker status and it says Docker is running. The problem is in next step when it says Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. But even if I run the daemon, it has issues, so not sure if any wait command will solve this

Comment: Doesn't run hello world download a docker repo if it doesn't already exist locally? Maybe thats the problem. Network permission maybe?

Comment: hmm, I really don't know. I don't need Hello world, I just tested it. The docker seems to be running, but as a next step I need to clone git repo and build the backend in that docker. Not sure how to do it in the just installed docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was I used `sudo` in `sudo docker run hello-world`. Without `sudo` it works...